# Convert a series of numbers into a string in Python

Tags: python

If I use raw_input, how can I convert a series of numbers such as 24, 45, 60 (It's important to note that the amount of numbers will be different each time) into ONE string?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? Please, give an exemple: input/expected.

Comment: This question has been asked here many times. Try to use search function.

Comment: if I get a series of numbers from the user through 
user_answer = raw_input(), how can I convert user_answer into a string?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague. This takes a list as input and forces into a single string separated by spaces.

```
raw_input = [24, 45, 60]
mystr = ' '.join(raw_input)

print mystr
#24 45 60
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not clearly stated. If you want to concatenate several numbers into one string like:

input: 24, 45, 60

output: "244560"

The following code will meet your requirements.

```
def list2string(input):
    return "".join([str(n) for n in input])

>>> list2string([24, 45, 60])
'244560'
```